# PC correct time issue in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I am using this to get my current PC time but it not giving me the exect time of my pc and giving me some other time which is not correct...
So how i can get my exact PC time in php??.
echo "The time is " . date("h:i:sa");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it off by hours? Look into setting the correct timezone.
http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php

Comment: is the timezone need to b select for time???

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you are saying. The default timezone of your PHP installation could be different than the timezone you want.

Comment: Ok i understand now Thank you so much bro

Comment: Accept the answer if it started working for you ;)